# Find replace digits in bash

Tags: bash

I need to print `16972 1684 173`, but `+` is not working, without `+` it does remove just one digit.

```
#!/bin/bash
numbers="16972,4 1684,15556 173,2"
echo $numbers
echo ${numbers//,[[:digit:]]+/}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match one or more occurrences of a pattern if you enable the `extglob` shell option:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo "${numbers//,+([0-9])/}"
16972 1684 173
```

See [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the Bash manual.

Comment: Good answer. @krish, note that bash parameter expansion tricks do not use regular expressions, they use shell patterns. Read the link in eugene's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we can rely on the format of `numbers` to be a whitespace-delimited sequence of comma-separated pairs of numbers, you can simply split the string into an array, then apply suffix removal to each element.

```
$ numbers="16972,4 1684,15556 173,2"
$ read -a arr <<< "$numbers"
$ echo "${arr[@]%,*}"
16972 1684 173
```

Comment: Why not `arr=($numbers)`?

Comment: In this case, you could, but in general I would worry about `$numbers` containing characters like `*` that could trigger pathname expansion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sed` instead

```
$ sed -r 's/,[0-9]+//g' <<< $numbers
16972 1684 173
```